# Water level sensor. How to read it?

Tags: oscillator, water, level

I have a water level sensor in which by varying the level of the water, an inductance change his value in a mobile coil. The sensor have the internal simple schematic like this (i don't know the value of the components)

[image]

The suggested working circuit use a Colpitts oscillator made by some HEX inverters, producing a frequency from 21 kHz to 25 kHz linked to the coil position and at the end to the water level by a provided lookup table.

I should read this frequency (level) by a micro, and I know how to do it, but in my project I used all the internal microcontroller timers. So, what I would ask, is if I can get around, using this variable inductance to produce a variable voltage to be read by the micro (avoiding to measure a frequency). And if it was possible avoiding a cascade of a Colpitts oscillator and a Frequency-Voltage converter (like the LM311).

Comment: You might want to re-evaluate how you're using the hardware timers. See this relevant question: [Software delay vs hardware timers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/103606/11683).

Answer (score 0):

You could buffer the oscillator output, then put it through a carefully designed low pass filter. You could do this in a number of ways, like R-C passively, or actively as a second stage,  or incorporated into the buffer.

Comment: I'm unsure of how this would translate into something measurable. What would low passing the sine/square wave accomplish?

Comment: @Michael sorry you are right... that only works as duty cycle conversion, not frequency conversion... maybe this will help https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://microcontrollerslab.com/frequency-to-voltage-converter-circuits/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwilo5zNn9zmAhWiwVkKHU7uASAQFjACegQIDhAK&usg=AOvVaw0KIkqxy3XfsvzDH4TMO_si&ampcf=1

Answer (score 0):

connect one end to one GPIO and the other end to another, test the pulse resposnse.

that's pretty much how "328 Mega LCR" works.

Comment: How does that work if there are no more timer resources?

Comment: the processor clock is still available: run a tight loop counting and hope for no interrupts (or detect and retry, or disable)

Comment: What "328 Mega LCR" stay for?

Answer (score 0):

The frequency can be measured to determine change of C due to water Dk= 80 x air.  This C change can be correlated with fluid  height.

[image]

If you really cannot figure out how to share or better utilize your HW timers , get a  counter with  a serial interface and measure frequency somehow then calibrate it.

Comment: Can you explain better to me how to proceed? I didn't realize well the "serial counter interface". Thanks.

Comment: do I have to explain how to measure frequency with an accurate time interval and counter? https://circuits4you.com/2016/05/13/arduino-frequency-counter/

Comment: No thanks, I already measure other signals with both the arduino interrupts and timer in my project and as you can see from the question i have timers busy. Timer 0 is used for millis() and timer1 as another frequency counter.  Timer 2 is not enough for the scope. Interrupt 0 and 1 are already used too. Your statement "serial interface" got me out of the solution you intended for. I could share the Timer1 stopping a process and start another, but I would use another approach if it exist for the problem, than Colpitts, like a direct voltage variation linked to the LC variation.